# Z-index not working even with relative position set and no elements with auto z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to make a paper doll kind of dissection game where you click and drag her internal organs for my personal site. I plan to have the bunny's stuffing and innards be under the body element to give the appearance that it's inside of it, then I plan to use javascript to make so when the innards are clicked, the z-index value increases so it shows up "outside" of body and the z-index returns to normal when mouse is released (felt this was important to state so any answers are ones that won't cause any interference with this function). The problem is the face, bow and tummy elements are under the "body" element and I don't know why. They're supposed to appear above it. The site in question is [here.](https://yumekawahanachi.neocities.org/dissectbunny)

My code is as follows:

```
<!--BODY-->

<div style="display: block; 

  z-index: 99;

  position:relative; 

  bottom: 2610px;

  height: 776px;

  width: 768px; 

  background-image: url(dissectbunny/bunny.body.png); 

  background-repeat: no-repeat; 

  background-position: center;

  background-size: cover;

  pointer-events: none;"></div>

<!--FLESH-->

<div name="face" id="face" style="z-index: 999; position: relative; left: 34.85%; bottom: 3322px; display: block; height: 230px; width: 232px; background-image: url(dissectbunny/bunny.face.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 12% ; background-size: 1024px;"></div>

<form name="tummy" id="tummy" style="z-index: 999; position: relative; left: 38.2%; bottom: 3315px; display: block; height: 184px; width: 178px; background-image: url(dissectbunny/bunny.tummy.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 51%; background-size: 1024px;"></form>

<div id="bandaid" style="z-index: 999;

  display: block;

  visibility: hidden;

  position:relative; 

  bottom: 3803px;

  height: 776px;

  width: 768px; 

  background-image: url(dissectbunny/bunny.bandaid.png); 

  background-repeat: no-repeat; 

  background-position: center;

  background-size: cover;

  pointer-events:none"></div>

  

<div id="bandage" style="z-index: 999;

  visibility: hidden;

  display: block;

  position:relative; 

  bottom: 4580px;

  height: 776px;

  width: 768px; 

  background-image: url(dissectbunny/bunny.bandage.png); 

  background-repeat: no-repeat; 

  background-position: center;

  background-size: cover;

  pointer-events:none;"></div>

</div>

<div name="bow" id="bow" style="z-index: 9999; position: relative; left: 34.5%; bottom: 5310px; display: block; height: 109px; width: 229px; background-image: url(dissectbunny/bunny.bow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 7% ; background-size: 1024px;"></div>
```

I don't know what else I'm doing wrong. No elements have an auto z-index, the z-index of the elements for the innards, skeleton and stuffing are all set to 9 with the exception of the back flesh which is set to 0. I have height, width and position relative set to everything. And the z-index of the bow, face and tummy are larger than that of the body. I tried making the z-index value scheme more chronological (1,2,3,4,etc.) to no avail. Deleting z-index properties entirely doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And the z-index of the bow, face and tummy are larger than that of the body.

The z-index of the bow, face, and tummy elements are all 10. The z-index of the body is 99. Just need to change the z-index of the bow, face, and tummy elements to 100.

The code you posted within your question doesn't match what is being display on the site, so perhaps the changed code wasn't updated on the page properly.

Comment: Really? Damn, I think I might need to copy the entire code and paste it into a new file then. \:

Comment: I tried doing that, no help. I tried setting the body to 9 which is less than 10 which got it to go below the face, bow and tummy but now the internal organs are above it too, even tho I set the z-index of them all the way from 8 to 0.

Comment: Yeh, at this point the body is attempting to either be above or below everything with no inbetween. I set the z-index of bow, face and tummy to 100 but it didn't help. EDIT: Ok nvm, I set the body to 10 and it worked. Yayyyy